# Show functions are solution to a system using matrices

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

Hello I have this problem I have for my diff eq practice exam and I really can't figure out where to start. The book is absolute worthless as well. So far I have made a matrix for the x' and y' functions similar to this:

[image]

Although now I really do not know how to show that x(t) and y(t) are solutions to the system.

Comment: Plug them back in to the differential equation and see if they work

Comment: Hi! Can you tell me which differential equation you are taking about?

Comment: Plug it into both of them. Your solution works only if both equations are satisfied

Comment: @ASKASK Sorry for the late reply! Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ are no vectors, so use them as given in the question, not like in your solution.

Apply them in the differential equation and check that they give the initial values.

What you apply to the matrix is 
$$
(x,y)^{\top} = (3e^t+7e^{-t},3e^t+21e^{-t})^{\top} 
$$
The result should be
$$
(x',y')^{\top} = (3e^t-7e^{-t},3e^t-21e^{-t})^{\top}
$$

Comment: So I don't use matrices for this?

Comment: See last sentence, you can, but it will not provide extra insight for now.

Comment: Hi mvw! Sorry for the late response. I got that result of the matrix you got above. But I am a little confused on where the initial conditions would come into play. Do you know where do I plug the initial conditions in?

Comment: Look at $(x, y )^T\vert_{t=0}$ and check if it is $(10,24)^T$.

Comment: Ohh I see now! Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy and requires no DiffEQ knowledge... just show those two functions satisfy those two equations. Take their derivatives and plug them in.

Comment: So I take the derivative of x(t) and set that derivative equal to 2x-y?

Comment: @1290 what do you mean "set" it equal? The derivative is what it is, you can't just "set" it to 17 or a chicken or whatever you think it should be at that minute. The question is literally asking you to show it is equal to that. You take the derivative and show that's what it is.

Comment: lol arite, chill. I am bad at math!!